# SQL using N-1 Dense Rank to filter out rows in dense rank N Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, window-functions

If my title isn't clear here's an example of what I am talking about.

Let's say I have a table that looks like this:

```
+----+------+----+----+---------+-------+---------+-------+
| ID | Time | X  | Y  | X_START | X_END | Y_START | Y_END |
+----+------+----+----+---------+-------+---------+-------+
|  1 |    0 |  8 |  6 |       6 |    10 |       4 |     8 |
|  2 |    0 | 20 | 10 |      18 |    22 |       8 |    12 |
|  3 |    1 |  8 |  8 |       6 |    10 |       6 |    10 |
|  4 |    1 | 10 | 24 |       8 |    12 |      22 |    26 |
+----+------+----+----+---------+-------+---------+-------+
```

If I apply this query to the table:

```
WITH 
cte1 AS (SELECT *,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY TIME) AS DENSE_RANK
    FROM data
    ORDER BY TIME)

SELECT * FROM cte1
```

I get:

```
+----+------+----+----+---------+-------+---------+-------+------------+
| ID | Time | X  | Y  | X_START | X_END | Y_START | Y_END | DENSE_RANK |
+----+------+----+----+---------+-------+---------+-------+------------+
|  1 |    0 |  8 |  6 |       6 |    10 |       4 |     8 |          1 |
|  2 |    0 | 20 | 10 |      18 |    22 |       8 |    12 |          1 |
|  3 |    1 |  8 |  8 |       6 |    10 |       6 |    10 |          2 |
|  4 |    1 | 10 | 24 |       8 |    12 |      22 |    26 |          2 |
+----+------+----+----+---------+-------+---------+-------+------------+
```

Now what I want to do is filter out any rows where X is within the range X_START - X_END AND Y is within the range Y_START - Y_END AND DENSE_RANK is n-1

so I'd like a result that looks like this:

```
+----+------+----+----+---------+-------+---------+-------+------------+
| ID | Time | X  | Y  | X_START | X_END | Y_START | Y_END | DENSE_RANK |
+----+------+----+----+---------+-------+---------+-------+------------+
|  1 |    0 |  8 |  6 |       6 |    10 |       4 |     8 |          1 |
|  2 |    0 | 20 | 10 |      18 |    22 |       8 |    12 |          1 |
|  4 |    1 | 10 | 24 |       8 |    12 |      22 |    26 |          2 |
+----+------+----+----+---------+-------+---------+-------+------------+
```

I am pretty new to SQL so I am not too sure on how to go about this. Thank you for all help in advance!

Comment: What is `n`?...

Comment: n is just any dense_rank value, so i always want to look at the prev dense_rank val

Comment: Why do you consider the 3d row of the results as the 1st of dense_rank=2? This row was arbitrarily chosen as 1st of dense_rank=2 since your ORDER BY clause sorts only by time.

Comment: There's another column called ID (which is the Primary Key) and I presume it just orders by that. I can add that in there if it's important

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `MIN()` window function to identify the minimum `ID` for each `Time` so that you can exclude that row if all the other conditions are satisfied too:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, 
           DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY TIME) AS `DENSE_RANK`,
           MIN(ID) OVER (PARTITION BY TIME) min_id
    FROM data
  )
SELECT ID, Time, X, Y, X_START, X_END, Y_START, Y_END, `DENSE_RANK` 
FROM cte
WHERE `DENSE_RANK` = 1 
  OR NOT (ID = min_id AND X BETWEEN X_START AND X_END AND Y BETWEEN Y_START AND Y_END)
ORDER BY `DENSE_RANK`, ID;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ac522b348853a8173ff029a31ffee9e6).